# How do I check if rmdir returns EEXIST or ENOTEMPTY?

Tags: linux, bash, return-value, errno, rmdir

I'm trying to write a bash script that asks for a directory then, after confirmation, removes the directory. I also need it to tell the user if the directory is not empty and to ask if they want to remove it anyway.

I figured I would use rmdir and check the return value to ensure the directory is deleted, and if not why, but so far I have no idea what return value equates to EEXIST or ENOTEMPTY. So far the only error value I've had return is 1.

What should the return value be if there are files in the directory?

Comment: show us what you have tried so far. 2 hints: Do you know that `echo $?` will show you the return from the previous command? Do you know that '0' returned means 'true'? Good luck.

Answer (score 2):

Do it in seperate checks. Not perfect, but a start

```
if [ ! -e "$DIR" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: $DIR does not exist" >&2
elif [ ! -d "$DIR" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: $DIR is not a directory" >&2
elif [ ! -r "$DIR" ]
then
    echo "ERROR: $DIR cannot be read" >&2
elif [ $(ls -a $DIR | wc -l) -gt 2 ]
then
    echo "ERROR: $DIR is not  empty" >&2
else
    rmdir $DIR
fi
```

NOTE: The `rmdir` could still possible fail. One that comes to mind is you don't have write permission on the parent directory of `$DIR`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try with this code:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_path() {
        if [ "x$1" = "x" ]
        then
                echo "ERROR: You have to specify a valid path."
                exit 1
        fi

        if ! [ -d "$1" ]
        then
                echo "ERROR: The specified path does not exists or it's not a directory"
                exit 1
        fi

        X="`find \"$1\"  -maxdepth 1 | tail -n 2 | wc -l`"
        if [ $X -gt 1 ]
        then
                X="R"
        else
                X=""
        fi

        while [[ "x$X" != "x" && ("x$X" != "xs" && "x$X" != "xn") ]]
        do
                echo "The specified path ($1) is not empty. Are you sure you want to delete it anyway? (S/n)"
                stty -echo
                read X
                stty echo
        done
        if [ "x$X" == "xn" ]
        then
                echo "Operation interrupted by the user."
                exit 0
        fi
}

echo -n "Please insert the path to delete: "
stty -echo
read DIRNAME
stty echo
echo

check_path "$DIRNAME"

echo "Removing path $1"
echo rm -fr "$DIRNAME"
```

HTH

Comment: you have to change the line "echo rm -fr " deleting "echo"